# How to get datetime type from column and not Timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `datetime` column:

```
>>> data_df.revoting_date
Out[9]: 
0    2017-01-09 08:40:50.241
1    2017-01-09 08:40:50.241
2    2017-01-09 08:40:50.241
3    2017-01-09 08:40:50.241
4    2017-01-09 08:40:50.241
5    2017-01-09 08:40:50.241
6    2017-01-09 08:40:50.241
7    2017-01-09 08:40:50.241
8    2017-01-09 08:40:50.241
9    2017-01-09 08:40:50.241
10   2017-01-09 08:40:50.241
11   2017-01-09 08:40:50.241
12   2017-01-09 08:40:50.241
13   2017-01-09 08:40:50.241
14   2017-01-09 08:40:50.241
Name: revoting_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But when I try to get an individual row I get `Timestamp` result:

```
data_df.revoting_date.iloc[0]
Out[11]: Timestamp('2017-01-09 08:40:50.241000')
```

How I can get the result as `datetime`?

Comment: Why does this matter? Is there something that you can't do with `Timestamp` that `datetime` gives you? Just want to understand the need here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
a = data_df.revoting_date.iloc[0].to_pydatetime()
print (a)
2017-01-09 08:40:50.241000

print (type(a))
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

and if need convert all values in column use [`to_pydatetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_pydatetime.html), but output is `numpy array`:

```
data_df.revoting_date.dt.to_pydatetime()
```

Answer (score 1):

slice with a list

```
data_df.revoting_date.iloc[[0]]

0
0    2017-01-09 08:40:50.241
Name: revoting_date, dtype: object
```

---

When you use `.iloc[0]` it will grab the lower dimensional object that resides at that position.  On the other hand, `.iloc[[0]]` grabs the set of lower dimensional objects at all positions in the list.  This set increases the dimensionality from a scalar timestamp back to a datetime column.